# Change login address

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing some `Web API`s alongside some `MVC` controllers and pages with `ASP.net MVC 5` and `Owin 1.0` . When not logged in, I want user to receive 401 error on Web API requests. Because of this I didn't add `<authentication>` section in `web.config`. I approached the goal by adding `AuthorizeAttribute`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        }
    }
```

and:

```
 public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        }
    }
```

It works fine for unauthorized web api request. The problem is with MVC controllers: They are redirected to http://localhost:1234/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f. Is there any way to either change the login address or completely remove it?

**Please note:**  My question is not about Web API since it behaves perfectly returning 401. I want to change behavior of MVC controller **to return my desired login page**

Comment: @Andrew My question is different: Web API behaves perfectly returning 401. I want to change behavior of MVC controller to return my desired login page.

Comment: OK then. Sorry. I'll try to answer you

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to change view (or route) for unauthorized user you should:

1) Check your `RouteConfig` and exactly default route. By default visual studio sets the default route `Home/Index` action. Here you can choose your own one;

2) Check your `Startup.Auth` file, which is a part of `Startup` partial class in `AppStart` folder. Here you have **all your OWIN authorization middleware setup**. One line of code is `LoginPath = PathString("~/Account/Login")`. This is the place where you can configure behavior of unauthorized request in MVC itself;

3) Check your `web.config` file just for sure that you do not use old style membership configuration rules

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much. Sounds like the solution. I'll check tomorrow and will come back to you soon.